# Elementary calculus equation

Tags: calculus, calculus-of-variations

If I have $L = y^2(1-y')^2$ are the following partial derivatives correct? Wolfram Alpha tells me otherwise...
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y} = 2y - 4yy' + 2y{y'}^2$$
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial y'}= -2y^2 + 2y^2y'$$
I'm mainly unsure about the second partial. This is part of a broader question where I am solving the Euler-Lagrange equation.

Comment: the second derivative is $-2y' y^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If you're treating $y$ and $y'$ as separate variables, then yes, you are correct.  I suspect Wolfram Alpha  doesn't know that $y$ and $y'$ are to be considered as separate variables.  It would give the correct answer if you used, say, $z$ instead of $y'$.